# Package war with specific profile in Spring Boot

Tags: maven, spring-boot, spring-profiles

I want to package a `war` for a specific profile. Is this possible? My `pom.xml` is configured properly to package `war` files and I'm packaging the app my with

```
mvn clean package
```

But, I don't know how I can provide the Spring profile in this command.

Thanks, any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't completely understand why? If you are looking for the application to always start with a certain profile then modify your `application.properties` to `spring.profiles.default=<specific profile>`